# How to restore JMS connection after restart of the server with JMS broker

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I have a JMS connection between my Java Spring Boot app and a remote server with a JMS broker. I use Apache Camel for it. Everything works pretty well until the server with JMS broker restarts: I just stop receiving any JMS messages and I even don't see any warnings in the logs. So the integration just not working.
I had a piece of code which I could trigger to refresh the configuration of JMS connection.

```
camelContext.stopRoute(routeId, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (!camelContext.removeRoute(routeId)) {
    throw new ApplicationException("Couldn't remove route " + routeId + " for agent " + agent.getSystemId());
}
camelContext.addRoutes(jmsReceiverRoute);
```

After this code executed I received hundreds of such same warnings:

```
 JmsConsumer[queue]] ERROR o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer:947 - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not allocate JMS connection due to RMI error.; nested exception is com.sap.engine.services.rmi_p4.P4RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
```

I think I have a workaround. If I recreate not only a route but also a component - looks like it starts working again:

```
camelContext.removeComponent(componentName);
JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
jmsConfiguration.setDestinationResolver((session, destinationName, pubSubDomain) -> queue);
agentJmsComponent = new JmsComponent(jmsConfiguration);
camelContext.addComponent(componentName, agentJmsComponent);
camelContext.addRoutes(jmsReceiverRoute);
```

I'm pretty sure it's not the best resolution (and would be happy to know the other ways) but **the main problem** is that I don't know how to say to my code that the JMS connection was broken in order to rebuild the camel components automatically. 
I mean I open the class `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and look at the method `executeOngoingLoop` which calls the method `invokeListener`.

```
private boolean invokeListener() throws JMSException {
 initResourcesIfNecessary();
 boolean messageReceived = receiveAndExecute(this, this.session, this.consumer);
 this.lastMessageSucceeded = true;
 return messageReceived;
}
```

But this variable - `messageReceived` - is false in both cases: when the connection broken and when there are really no any messages in the queue (which is a normal situation).

So now I have 2 questions:

1. Do you think my workaround is satisfactory to rebuilt the camel route?
2. Is it possible to understand that the JMS broker was restarted and to restore the connection automatically (preferably using only JMS setting - not rebuilding the camel route).

Comment: which JMS provider do you have configured ? Usually the provider's fault-tolerance should make the broker restart transparent to Camel

Comment: I believe SonicMQ, but not sure because this server is actually a SAP PI/PO system which we connect our app to. So theoretically it can be any broker and we can't do anything with that.